# Verify and set list parameter in function of mock object

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

I have and interface IDatabaseInteraction:

```
public interface IDatabaseInteraction
{
    void FillAppSection(List<AppSectionId> appSectionIds);
}
```

The definition for AppSectionId is:

```
public class AppSectionId
{
    public string App;
    public string Section;
    public int Id;
}
```

I abstracted the database call into IDatabaseInteraction for the class under test.
The list comes in (in this testcase 1 item in appSectionIds) and is updated in the FillAppSection method, the Id gets filled.
I want to check the items App and Section values and secondly, I want to set the Id.
How do I do that using moq?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would typically change that method to return a `List<AppSectionId>` as I think that is clearer. However, if you want to continue like this then you can use the Moq `Callback` method, something like this:

```
Mock<IDatabaseInteraction> databaseInteraction = new Mock<IDatabaseInteraction>();
databaseInteraction.Setup(x => x.FillAppSection(It.IsAny<List<AppSectionId>>())).Callback((List<AppSectionId> x) => x.Add(someObject));
```

Inside the `Callback` method you can then setup the `List` however you like.